# Sqlite select unique segment of string

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using Sqlite3.7.15.
I have a column named color which contains comma separated numbers, e.g. Color1,Color3,Color15 and another row with only 'Color15'.
I want to get all rows that contain 'Color1',

```
Select color from table where color like '%Color1%';
```

returns a row which contains, e.g. Color 15.
If I use

```
Select color from table where color like '%Color15,%'; //(note comma at end)
```

I won't get the row with Color 15 (if that is the last item in the string.
I guess I could terminate all strings with a comma and adjust accordingly, but that seems clumsy.

I tried `instr(color,'Color1')>0`; (on a sqlite3.7.15 version, but that did not help)
My sqlite3 database is supporting an app targeted for Android 2.3 (gingerbread).

I will try to make this clearer;
Here are the first 10 rows with sample queries, none correct:

```
1|Color2,Color4,Color3
2|Color6,Color12,Color3
3|Color1,Color2,Color3
4|Color1,Color2
5|Color1,Color2,Color3
6|Color6,Color12,Color3
7|Color2,Color3,Color13
8|Color8,Color4,Color3,Color1
9|Color2,Color5,Color3,Color1
10|Color11,Color12,Color5,Color2,Color1,Color3
```

“sqlite> select _id,color from identity where color like 'Color1';” – No rows returned.

“sqlite> select _id,color from identity where color like '%Color1';” - returns

```
8|Color8,Color4,Color3,Color1
9|Color2,Color5,Color3,Color1
```

“select _id,color from identity where color like 'Color1%';” – returns

```
3|Color1,Color2,Color3
4|Color1,Color2
5|Color1,Color2,Color3
10|Color11,Color12,Color5,Color2,Color1,Color3
```

“select _id,color from identity where color like '%Color1%';” – returns

```
2|Color6,Color12,Color3
3|Color1,Color2,Color3
4|Color1,Color2
5|Color1,Color2,Color3
6|Color6,Color12,Color3
7|Color2,Color3,Color13
8|Color8,Color4,Color3,Color1
9|Color2,Color5,Color3,Color1
10|Color11,Color12,Color5,Color2,Color1,Color3
```

select _id,color from identity where color like '%Color1,%';(Note comma) - returns

```
3|Color1,Color2,Color3
4|Color1,Color2
5|Color1,Color2,Color3
10|Color11,Color12,Color5,Color2,Color1,Color3
```

The correct return is

```
3|Color1,Color2,Color3
4|Color1,Color2
5|Color1,Color2,Color3
8|Color8,Color4,Color3,Color1
9|Color2,Color5,Color3,Color1
10|Color11,Color12,Color5,Color2,Color1,Color3
```

The database also supports the iOS version of the app, using Core Data, so the fewer changes to the database, the better.

Comment: You may want to learn about database normalization http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization and things like 3NF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by changing the database column to comma separated colors, e.g. Gray,Black,Violet rather than Color1,Color3,Color15. This way, the sql statement: Select color from table where color like '%Violet%'; returned the expected result.
Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use Color 15 without the ,?

```
Select color from table where color like '%Color15%'
```

Or short of that, try this:

```
select color from table where color like '%Color15,%' OR color like '%Color15'
```